# What cross-browser charting packages are available?

Tags: javascript, browser, charts

I want to include some charts on my website and I'm looking for a good cross-browser charting package - what are my options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prefer jQuery one:
http://www.flotcharts.org/

Examples:
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Comment: @AutomatedTester: "The plugin is known to work with Internet Explorer 6/7/8 (IE8 only in development version), Firefox 2.x+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Konqueror 4.x+. If you find a problem, please report it. Drawing is done with the canvas tag introduced by Safari and now available on all major browsers, except Internet Explorer where the excanvas Javascript emulation helper is used." From the first link in the answer.

Comment: I like the jQuery ones as well - eye-catching and clear.  I am looking at these examples in IE7 and they look okay to me.

Comment: And if javascript is disabled?

Comment: Flot works fine in IE6 and up. Well, slowish, but fine for most charts. That's what Stack Overflow uses.

Answer (score 12):

Google Chart API is really powerful, and unlike flot does not rely on javascript being enabled.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: I like this but I just don't like the way I can't download it and put it on my own server.

Comment: Browser cache my friend... browser cache.  That or look at whats retreived in firebug's NET tab.

Comment: A API compatible charting solution is available for Java based web apps called Eastwood (based on JFree chart). See http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/

Answer (score 12):

Can you be a bit more descriptive about what style charts you're looking for? Simple charts like line, bar and pie graphs are understandably more widely implemented. If you're looking for more complex ones such as gantt, sparklines or real-time / data streaming charts it narrows your options substantially.

As far as being cross browser compatible, flash and HTML canvas are both pretty well supported and most people will be able to view the charts if you use either method of delivery.

**There are several free flash charting solutions that work superbly well.**

- I found it really easy to work with FusionCharts and they also have released plenty under a FREE licence. See : *http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/Gallery.asp*
- Also see PHP / SWF Charts : *http://www.maani.us/charts/index.php*

> XML/SWF Charts is free to download and
>   use. The free, unregistered version
>   contains all the features except for:
>
> ```
> - Clicking a chart takes the user to the XML/SWF Charts web site. 
> - No displaying charts inside another flash file.
> - No technical support, and no product updates by e-mail.
> ```

« *The click redirect makes me prefer fusioncharts*

- Google have released charts (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), as has Yahoo (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts) but personally, I prefer to keep the swf source files together with my website. The additional bandwidth is not that large.

Then as Justin Niessner mentioned, there is also *[Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)*.

If you prefer to go the **HTML Canvas** route, try:
 - *http://code.google.com/p/flot/* (as mentioned by Andrejs Cainikovs)
 - *http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/*

If you're using **PHP**, here's one : *http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/*

If **None of the Above** are a viable option and you want a really simple chart (bar, line) then consider using CSS charts:

- *http://grassegger.at/xperimente/charts-daten-semantik-css/*
- oops, forgot to append the css line graph. Here it is : *http://cssglobe.com/post/4175/pure-css-line-graph*

Answer (score 8):

Not quite charting, but lightweight SVG/VML cross-browser graphic library: [raphaeljs.com](http://raphaeljs.com).

Very easy to make charts.

Answer (score 3):

Another Flash & cash solution is [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you consider Flash to be cross browser and don't mind spending some money this is a good option:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/

Comment: Well, except for mobile, I guess Flash is cross-browser. Some of the JavaScript ones work on iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try the [jQuery Visualize plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_visualize_plugin_accessible_charts_graphs_from_tables_html5_canvas). It's very simple to implement, all you need is a table with your data in and then in JavaScript call the plugin and bam it'll work.

For cross-browser support they say:

> We have tested this plugin in the
>   following browsers: IE6, IE7, IE8,
>   Firefox 2, Firefox 3.5, Safari 3 and
>   4, Opera 9.

Answer (score 2):

Got to go with [gchart](http://code.google.com/p/gchart/).

I've used this in several browsers.

[Short tutorial.](http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/264/simple-charts-in-gwt-with-gchart/)

Comment: Nice - hadn't heard of this - GWT charts with no round-trips.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for your project, you might also want to check out some of the Flash charting packages like [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/).

You could also try using some of the Flex functionality.

That way no matter what browser your user is using, you're running on a consistant runtime.

Answer (score 1):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is nice.  Not the most fully-featured charting system, but it does what it does really well.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo charting also works OK (and uses SVG/VML rather than Canvas/ExCanvas, which means you can do funkier things with it if you look at its internals), but flot is nicer to program with imo.

Answer (score 1):

I would second Open Flash Chart, I have used it extensively and would especially recommend the DZ patched version at [OFC-2](http://ofc2dz.com/index.html).

You can see it in use at [Red5 Analytics Demo](http://www.nbred5.com/AnalyticsDemo)

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to use [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) for this. Sadly, IE can't display it without installing an unsupported third party [add-in](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/mainframed.html).

Comment: Dojo's 2D graphics package, underlying their graphs, uses SVG on most browsers and VML on IE. There may be other similar implementations around.

Comment: Indeed, thevs' answer above mentions another.

Comment: And one more comment for luck: Google's got an 'SVG for IE' plugin, keep an eye out for people writing graphics packages that target that rather than canvas/excanvas.  For graphing, SVG is more appropriate than canvas.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For true cross-browser support I would recommend image graphs generated on the server.

If this isn't attainable use Flash-based plugins. This is the most widely-supported clientside solution. Otherwise resort to Javascript - it may require HTML5, or non-IE browsers, or ..

If you're seeking a simple graph in HTML table see [here](http://concepts.waetech.com/bargraph/). Far from recommended though!

Comment: The HTML graph has its uses.  Specifically, if you'r e trying to do a 100-column bar graph - and yes, it does have its uses - then doing it horizontally is fine, because you expect it to run off-page and scroll, and doing it with images is distinctly *not* fine, because the image ends up huge.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/09/a-quick-comparison-of-web-based-charting-libraries-for-data-visualization