# Easiest way to generate graphs

Tags: php, extjs, graph

I'm trying to generate a graph for the statics of my site.

I need a couple of them, one for the hours of a day, one for the days of a week, one for the weeks of a  month and one for the months of a year.

There are hits and unique visitors.

It could look like:
http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/chart/charts.html - The last example.

But i don't know how to get it working without the framework...

I'm using the Kohana PHP5 Framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have to build complex and interactive charts you could try Google Chart, it's super easy...

example:

```
<img src="https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World" />
```

produce:

[image]

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [pChart project](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). It is quite easy to use and looks quite good.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it being non-flash, there is [Image_Graph](http://pear.php.net/Image_Graph) from PEAR

Answer (score 0):

If this question is which charting solution to use, see [another reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227391/what-cross-browser-charting-packages-are-available/1280694#1280694)

If it's more about using charts with ExtJs then, from version 3.0 onwards, charting comes standard. See [documentation](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.chart.Chart) or [examples](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html#sample-4). Have a look at the source of the examples to see how the store is loaded and the chart draws data from the store.

It doesn't matter what server side technology you're using, provided that you can send your data to the browser and bind a store to that data. ExtJs provided binding to XML as well as JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

The latest ExtJS 3.0 has a simple line and bar charting. You can also look at [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) for simple and lighweight charting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using flash and you are using php on the server, then have a look at [Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) I have successfully integrated it with ExtJS for display Google Analytics Data.

See the write up of my [Analytics Demo](http://www.nbred5.com/content/ExtJS/Red5AnalyticsDemo_1.html)

Answer (score 0):

[FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) is a flash based options that works very well.  They even have a [free version](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/Default.asp).  There's a nice API for PHP.

One issue...they do not print unless you specifically print the graph.  (This is true for most, if not all flash stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Google Chart - nice and easy to use.
- dojox.charting - http://dojotoolkit.org/projects/dojox
- CSS - example: CSS For Bar Graphs - http://applestooranges.com/blog/post/css-for-bar-graphs/
- HTML tables - for bar graphs (set your TD = 0-100%) - you may find some examples at google ("html table graphs").